# angular filter which convert date and time to single formatted string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime

I am using data from a API, which returns a date and time in two different key/value pair (date and time).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ctrl">

  Date {{date}} - Time {{time}}
  <br/>
  {{date  | dateformatter}}

</body>
</html>
```

```js
angular.module("app",[]).controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.date = "03/13/2014";
  $scope.time = "8:10:56";

}).filter("dateformatter", function($filter){
  // this should return 'yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss'
  return function(dt) {
    return "2014 03 13 8:10:56";
  }
})
```

Can I use a filter to convert it to a single formatted string?

[**Here's an example in jsBin**](http://jsbin.com/kucamapa/2/edit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would convert `Date` and `Time` to `Date` object and use <kbd>[Date filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)</kbd>

So controller looks like:

```
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.date = "03/13/2014";
  $scope.time = "8:10:56";

  $scope.newDate = new Date( $scope.date + ' ,' + $scope.time).getTime();     
});
```

and *HTML:*

```
{{newDate  | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss'}}
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/1199/)**</kbd>

Comment: is it possible without creating newDate, actually my data is in an array, and i am using it in ng-repeat.

Comment: Date filter effects on `date` object. Why you dont want to use `Date` object?

Comment: I made this filter that uses Moment.js and will take any date string or JavaScript date object. Plus, it has the ability to use any Moment.js transform function, like 'fromNow'.
https://gist.github.com/cmmartin/341b017194bac09ffa1a

Answer (score 1):

An other quick way to do that :

```
angular
.module('PrivateModule')
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.Date = function(date) {
        return new Date(date);
    }

}
```

Then in your view :

```
<span>{{Date(obj.start) | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt:

```
+(function(angular, undefined) {
  angular
    .module('app')
    .filter('timestamp', filter);

  function filter() {
    return function filterFn(input) {
      return ( Date.parse(input) );
    }
  }
})(angular);
```

Usage: `{{ date | timestamp | date: 'MMM d, yyyy' }}`. In your case, `{{ date + ' ,' + time  | timestamp | date: 'MMM d, yyyy' }}`.

This is a better solution, removing concerns that do *not* belong to a controller.

Will be making this available to bower soon, [check *my* repository](https://github.com/srph/angular-timestamp-filter), if ever that's better than a copy-pasting the [gist / snippet](https://gist.github.com/srph/9ddfc25e98f4e09dc11c) (whatever suits the dev).